# paste special only specific range

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I have reverse engineered and developed a code thanks to all your efforts here but I have come unstuck on one small thing. What I want to do when copying from WS2 is to paste as special as I do not want to export all the formulas contained in columns `AD:AR` which have caused the workbook to crash.

```
Sub Copyandpaste()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RAW DATA")
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DATA INPUT")

    LastRow = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    With ws2
        .Range("A2:AR2" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
        For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
                PT.RefreshTable
            Next PT
        Next WS
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You mentioned  `AD:AR` but the code says `A:AR`?

Comment: add .Value ?  Destination:=ws1.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value

Comment: There is something wrong here: `.Range("A2:AR2" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)`. Please check it...

Comment: Yes Code copies A2:AR2 however, the makeup is that from A:AC its all text, dates & numbers but from AD:AR its calculated formulas. I dont want to copy the formulas but the numbers only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Copyandpaste()
    Dim ws1LRow As Long, ws2LRow As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW DATA")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA INPUT")

    With ws1
        ws1LRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=.Range("A1"), _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row + 1
    End With

    With ws2
        ws2LRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A2:AR" & ws2LRow).Copy

        ws1.Range("A" & ws1LRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'        For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
'            For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
'                PT.RefreshTable
'            Next PT
'        Next WS
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code its working great. Is there a way of tweaking so that it doesn't keep the copy selection active after completing. Probaby asking a tad too much I know.

Comment: Add this line `Application.CutCopyMOde = False` after you finish pasting :)